# Typescript errors when building an Angular module in AOT

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an Angular module manually with Webpack without using the CLI.
When doing normal build it works, when doing AOT build it doesn't!

The tsconfig.aot.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit": true,
    "genDir": "aot"
  }
}
```

The errors are mostly related to Typescript:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:829:20
>       TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1486:36
>       TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1490:43
>       TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2305:36
>       TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2309:43
>       TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2313:50
>       TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:82:59
>       TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: What is your `@types/core-js` version?

Comment: "@types/core-js": "~2.5.0",

Comment: are you getting any error while compiling the code with ng serve?

Comment: Since the errors seem to be in the library, if you want, you can disable TS from checking library types. For that add `"skipLibCheck": true,` to `compilerOptions` in *tsconfig.json*

Comment: @BlizZard I am not using CLI, I am doing it manually. `npm run build` works fine, when I run `npm run build:prod` I get the issues with types. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason the normal build "works" is because you have the `transpileOnly: true` option set on `awesome-typescript-loader`, which disables all type error reporting.  Once I remove that option and set the `lib` settings the same in both `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.aot.json`, I get roughly the same errors from both `npm run build` and `npm run build:prod`.

Starting from the zip file you posted, one configuration that worked for me was to upgrade `@types/core-js` to the latest version as of this writing (2.5.0, which is a much closer match to your `core-js` version of 2.5.7 than `@types/core-js` 0.9.* was) and then change the `target` to `es6` (and remove the overriding `lib` options) in both `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.aot.json`.  After doing this, both `npm run build` and `npm run build:prod` completed without error for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use `"@types/core-js": "0.9.35"` in you `package.json` and then run `npm install`. That will fix it.

Comment: Even more errors. I've uploaded the small project here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1li-zzJLDSVfSAOAYNcTG8AKz5qXREHJp